# c# ClientWebSocket creating mulitple websocket connections

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I'm working on a .net core project where I need to create multiple websocket connections to a ws server using the ClientWebSocket class.

Below is the code to connect to the server and I am able to receive data in the while loop. However, none of the code after this works until the websocket is closed.

How do I create multiple websocket clients? Do I create a new long running Task everytime I need to create a new ws client?

Thank you in advance

```cs
using (ClientWebSocket ws = new ClientWebSocket())
{
    await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri(url), CancellationToken.None);

    var msgbuf = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)));

    await ws.SendAsync(msgbuf, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    

        var buffer = WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer(4096, 4096);
        while (ws.State != WebSocketState.Closed && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var receiveResult = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);
            // if the token is cancelled while ReceiveAsync is blocking, the socket state changes to aborted and it can't be used
            if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // the server is notifying us that the connection will close; send acknowledgement
                if (ws.State == WebSocketState.CloseReceived && receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nAcknowledging Close frame received from server");
                    await ws.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Acknowledge Close frame", CancellationToken.None);
                }

                // display text or binary data
                if (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open && receiveResult.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    if (receiveResult.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string message = "";
                        if (receiveResult.EndOfMessage == false)
                        {
                            message += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            message += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count);
                            HandleMessage(message, cancellationTokenSource);
                            message = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Ending processing loop in state {ws.State}");

    return ws;
}
```

Comment: On client side it doesn't matter long-running or not. But the code is asynchronous (you need no Thread), expose the code to separate `async` method, then call as many times as needed. Create `List<Task> tasks`, store there running tasks. Use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` to wait for all the tasks completion.

Comment: Thansk aepot!! was able to make it work